# erlang failed to resolve ipv6 addresses using parameter from rabbitmq

Tags: rabbitmq, erlang, ipv6

I'm using rabbitmq cluster in k8s which has only pure ipv6 address. inet return nxdomain error when parsing the k8s service name.
The paramter passed to erlang from rabbitmq is:

```
RABBITMQ_SERVER_ADDITIONAL_ERL_ARGS="+A 128  -kernel inetrc '/etc/rabbitmq/erl_inetrc'  -proto_dist inet6_tcp"
RABBITMQ_CTL_ERL_ARGS="-proto_dist inet6_tcp"


 erl_inetrc: |-
    {inet6, true}.
```

when rabbitmq using its plugin rabbit_peer_discovery_k8s to invoke k8s api:

```
   2019-10-15 07:33:55.000 [info] <0.238.0> Peer discovery backend does not support locking, falling back to randomized delay
2019-10-15 07:33:55.000 [info] <0.238.0> Peer discovery backend rabbit_peer_discovery_k8s does not support registration, skipping randomized start
up delay.
2019-10-15 07:33:55.000 [debug] <0.238.0> GET https://kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local:443/api/v1/namespaces/tazou/endpoints/zt4-crmq
2019-10-15 07:33:55.015 [debug] <0.238.0> Response: {error,{failed_connect,[{to_address,{"kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local",443}},{inet,[inet]
,nxdomain}]}}
2019-10-15 07:33:55.015 [debug] <0.238.0> HTTP Error {failed_connect,[{to_address,{"kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local",443}},{inet,[inet],nxdom
ain}]}
2019-10-15 07:33:55.015 [info] <0.238.0> Failed to get nodes from k8s - {failed_connect,[{to_address,{"kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local",443}}
,
                 {inet,[inet],nxdomain}]}
2019-10-15 07:33:55.016 [error] <0.237.0> CRASH REPORT Process <0.237.0> with 0 neighbours exited with reason: no case clause matching {error,"{fa
iled_connect,[{to_address,{\"kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local\",443}},\n                 {inet,[inet],nxdomain}]}"} in rabbit_mnesia:init_from
_config/0 line 167 in application_master:init/4 line 138
2019-10-15 07:33:55.016 [info] <0.43.0> Application rabbit exited with reason: no case clause matching {error,"{failed_connect,[{to_address,{\"kub
ernetes.default.svc.cluster.local\",443}},\n
```

in k8s console, the address could be resolved:

```
[rabbitmq]# nslookup -type=AAAA kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local
Server:         2019:282:4000:2001::6
Address:        2019:282:4000:2001::6#53

kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local    has AAAA address fd01:abcd::1
```

the inet could return ipv6 address.

```
kubectl exec -ti zt4-crmq-0 rabbitmqctl eval 'inet:gethostbyname("kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local").'
{ok,{hostent,"kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local",[],inet6,16,
             [{64769,43981,0,0,0,0,0,1}]}}
```

as I know, plugin call httpc:request to invoke k8s api. I don't know what's the gap between httpc:request and inet:gethostbyname. I also don't what's used by httpc:request to resolve the address of hostname.
I query for the rabbitmq plugin, It's said that rabbitmq plugin don't aware how erlang resovlve the address.  https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-peer-discovery-k8s/issues/55.

Anything else I could set for erl_inetrc so that erlang could resolve the ipv6 address? what did i miss to config? or how could i debug from erlang side? I'm new to erlang.

B.R,
Tao

Comment: Instead of asking every forum available, I suggest keeping this discussion on the `rabbitmq-users` mailing list. It is unlikely anyone on this site can help.

Comment: https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-peer-discovery-k8s/issues/55#issuecomment-543228426

Comment: I had posted it to the plugin site. but they said it's related to erlang configuration.

Comment: Please test the build available [here](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-peer-discovery-k8s/issues/55#issuecomment-543228426).